# Flex RadioButton Skin With Transparent Background Which Allows Mouse Clicks Through

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, button, actionscript

I'm sure this must be simple but I can't see it.

I have created a Skin for a RadioButton which is essentially a square Group with a triangle inside it. The tip of the triangle is at the centre of the square. All the artwork is vector paths and defined within the MXML.

When I position the RadioButtons within my UI they overlap each other, though the triangles which are visible do not.

When I click on the RadioButtons I can't click through the transparent areas of topmost RadioButtons to the triangular artwork of RadioButtons beneath. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please?

Here is the current Skin file:

```
<s:Skin
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        alpha.disabledStates="0.5">

  <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[
    /**
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.RadioButton")]
    ]]>
  </fx:Metadata>

  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    /**
     * @private
     */
    private static const focusExclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function get focusSkinExclusions():Array { return focusExclusions;};
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overStates" />
    <s:State name="down" stateGroups="downStates" />
    <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates" />
    <s:State name="upAndSelected" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="overAndSelected" stateGroups="overStates, selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="downAndSelected" stateGroups="downStates, selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="disabledAndSelected" stateGroups="disabledStates, selectedStates" />
  </s:states>

  <!-- Main artwork Group defining scale -->
  <s:Group
          scaleX="0.175" scaleY="0.175">

    <s:Group
            width="1024" height="1024">

      <!-- Up Artwork -->
      <s:Group
              id="viewpointUp"
              excludeFrom="selectedStates">

        <s:Path id="BeamDisabled" x="183.549" y="31.3008" winding="nonZero" data="M0 0 328.451 480.698 656.902 0">
          <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient x="328.452" y="480.698" scaleX="480.698" rotation="270">
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="#BFBFBF"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.570107" color="#EBEBEB" alpha="0.429893"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
          </s:fill>
        </s:Path>
        <s:Ellipse id="SpotDisabledEllipse" x="477" y="477" width="70" height="70">
          <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#BFBFBF"/>
          </s:fill>
          <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke weight="8" miterLimit="10" color="#FFFFFF"/>
          </s:stroke>
          <s:filters>
            <s:GlowFilter blurX="16" blurY="16" quality="2" color="#000000" alpha="0.25"/>
          </s:filters>
        </s:Ellipse>
      </s:Group>

      <!-- Up and Selected Artwork -->
      <s:Group
              id="viewpointSelected"
              includeIn="selectedStates">

        <s:Path id="BeamEnabled" x="183.549" y="31.3008" winding="nonZero" data="M0 0 328.451 480.698 656.902 0">
          <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient x="328.452" y="480.698" scaleX="480.698" rotation="270">
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="#14948B"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.29695" color="#6FBDB8" alpha="0.70305"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.570107" color="#B6DEDB" alpha="0.429893"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.815192" color="#E9F5F4" alpha="0.184808"/>
              <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" color="#FFFFFF" alpha="0"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
          </s:fill>
        </s:Path>
        <s:Ellipse id="SpotEnabledEllipse" x="477" y="477" width="70" height="70">
          <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#14948B"/>
          </s:fill>
          <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke weight="8" miterLimit="10" color="#FFFFFF"/>
          </s:stroke>
          <s:filters>
            <s:GlowFilter blurX="16" blurY="16" quality="2" color="#000000" alpha="0.25"/>
          </s:filters>
        </s:Ellipse>
      </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
  </s:Group>

  <!-- Label -->
  <!---  @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
  <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
           textAlign="start"
           verticalAlign="middle"
           maxDisplayedLines="1"
           left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" />
</s:Skin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the x and y values that you have specified in your skin file. When you apply these skins to the radiobutton  the x value = 183 and y = 33 will not work as radio button will take small place in your actual application.

The x and y values must be zeroes for ellipse

and now remove x and y for the path also and set horizontalCenter =0 and verticalCenter = 0.

and if possible specify minimum width and height to ellipse and path also and make sure the path width should be smaller than that of ellipse

Hope this works

Comment: Visually everything is fine. The artwork was created in Illustrator and exported as FXG and then adjusted to become the MXML file, this is why it has the x and y values to position the `Paths` in the `Group`. Of the 4 of these RadioButtons which I have used in my UI 2 of them are uppermost and apart from each other and when clicked on work just fine so I think the artwork is not the problem.

Comment: Not able to understand ur problem . Can you please post the sample code  or an Image of how you are positioning the radiobutton ?